# com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator not found

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working on google endpoints api 2.0 and was trying to integrate firebase authentication using [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users)

Part of documentation. I encountered a peculiar problem that with the dependencies that I have added to pom.xml com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator.class doesn't show up. There are other authenticators available such as GoogleJwtAuthenticator and  GoogleOAuth2Authenticator, but EspAuthenticator is not available for import. It is not recognised. Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <groupId>com.google.devrel.training.conference</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.53</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta5</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- plugin configuration -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints</directory>
                            <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.google.appengine
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            appengine-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.9.3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                endpoints_get_discovery_doc
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my ConferenceApi Code, that I developed from udacity course building scalable apps with java and later migrated to 2.0 version using the migration guide.

```
package com.google.devrel.training.conference.spi;

import static com.google.devrel.training.conference.service.OfyService.ofy;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.GoogleOAuth2Authenticator;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator; // not available


import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiIssuer;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiIssuerAudience;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod.HttpMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.Constants;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.domain.Conference;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.domain.Profile;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ConferenceForm;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ConferenceQueryForm;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ProfileForm;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ProfileForm.TeeShirtSize;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.service.OfyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query;

/**
 * Defines conference APIs.
 */
@Api(name = "conference", version = "v1", scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE }, 
authenticators = {com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator.class},
//EspAuthenticator not available
issuers = {
        @ApiIssuer(
                name = "firebase",
                issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/***PROJECT ID***",
                jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
     },
issuerAudiences = {
        @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "***PROJECT ID***")
    },
clientIds = {
        Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, description = "API for the Conference Central Backend application.")
public class ConferenceApi {

    /*
     * Get the display name from the user's email. For example, if the email is
     * lemoncake@example.com, then the display name becomes "lemoncake."
     */
    private static String extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(String email) {
        return email == null ? null : email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
    }

    /**
     * Creates or updates a Profile object associated with the given user
     * object.
     *
     * @param user
     *            A User object injected by the cloud endpoints.
     * @param profileForm
     *            A ProfileForm object sent from the client form.
     * @return Profile object just created.
     * @throws UnauthorizedException
     *             when the User object is null.
     */

    // Declare this method as a method available externally through Endpoints
    @ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    // The request that invokes this method should provide data that
    // conforms to the fields defined in ProfileForm

    // TODO 1 Pass the ProfileForm parameter
    // TODO 2 Pass the User parameter
    public Profile saveProfile(final User user,ProfileForm profileForm) throws UnauthorizedException {

        String userId = null;
        String mainEmail = null;
        String displayName = "Your name will go here";
        TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize = TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED;

        // TODO 2
        // If the user is not logged in, throw an UnauthorizedException
        if(user==null){
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized Exception");
        }

        // TODO 1
        // Set the teeShirtSize to the value sent by the ProfileForm, if sent
        // otherwise leave it as the default value



        // TODO 1
        // Set the displayName to the value sent by the ProfileForm, if sent
        // otherwise set it to null
//        displayName=profileForm.getDisplayName();

        // TODO 2
        // Get the userId and mainEmail
        userId=user.getUserId();
        mainEmail=user.getEmail();

        // TODO 2
        // If the displayName is null, set it to default value based on the user's email
        // by calling extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(...)
//        if(displayName==null){
//          displayName=extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(mainEmail);
//        }


        // Create a new Profile entity from the
        // userId, displayName, mainEmail and teeShirtSize
        Key<Profile> key=Key.create(Profile.class,userId);
        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(key).now();

        if(profile==null){

             if(profileForm.getTeeShirtSize()!=null){
                teeShirtSize=profileForm.getTeeShirtSize();
             }else{
                 teeShirtSize=TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED;
             }

             if(profileForm.getDisplayName()!=null){
                 displayName=profileForm.getDisplayName();
             }else{
                 displayName=extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(mainEmail);
             }
             profile=new Profile(userId,displayName, mainEmail, teeShirtSize);
        }else{
            profile.update(profileForm.getDisplayName(), profileForm.getTeeShirtSize());
        }

        // TODO 3 (In Lesson 3)
        // Save the Profile entity in the datastore
        ofy().save().entity(profile).now();

        // Return the profile
        return profile;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Profile object associated with the given user object. The cloud
     * endpoints system automatically inject the User object.
     *
     * @param user
     *            A User object injected by the cloud endpoints.
     * @return Profile object.
     * @throws UnauthorizedException
     *             when the User object is null.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public Profile getProfile(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }

        // TODO
        // load the Profile Entity
        String userId = user.getUserId(); // TODO
        Key<Profile> key = Key.create(Profile.class,userId); // TODO
        Profile profile=(Profile) ofy().load().key(key).now(); // TODO load the Profile entity
        return profile;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Profile entity for the current user
     * or creates it if it doesn't exist
     * @param user
     * @return user's Profile
     */
    private static Profile getProfileFromUser(User user) {
        // First fetch the user's Profile from the datastore.
        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(
                Key.create(Profile.class, user.getUserId())).now();
        if (profile == null) {
            // Create a new Profile if it doesn't exist.
            // Use default displayName and teeShirtSize
            String email = user.getEmail();
            profile = new Profile(user.getUserId(),
                    extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(email), email, TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED);
        }
        return profile;
    }

/**
     * Creates a new Conference object and stores it to the datastore.
     *
     * @param user A user who invokes this method, null when the user is not signed in.
     * @param conferenceForm A ConferenceForm object representing user's inputs.
     * @return A newly created Conference Object.
     * @throws UnauthorizedException when the user is not signed in.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "createConference", path = "conference", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public Conference createConference(final User user, final ConferenceForm conferenceForm)
        throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Get the userId of the logged in User
        String userId = user.getUserId();

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Get the key for the User's Profile
        Key<Profile> profileKey = Key.create(Profile.class,userId);

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Allocate a key for the conference -- let App Engine allocate the ID
        // Don't forget to include the parent Profile in the allocated ID
        final Key<Conference> conferenceKey = OfyService.factory().allocateId(profileKey, Conference.class);

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Get the Conference Id from the Key
        final long conferenceId = conferenceKey.getId();

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Get the existing Profile entity for the current user if there is one
        // Otherwise create a new Profile entity with default values
        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(profileKey).now();
        if(profile==null){
            profile=new Profile(user.getUserId(),user.getEmail(),extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(user.getEmail()),TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED);


        }

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Create a new Conference Entity, specifying the user's Profile entity
        // as the parent of the conference
        Conference conference = new Conference(conferenceId,user.getUserId(),conferenceForm);

        // TODO (Lesson 4)
        // Save Conference and Profile Entities
         ofy().save().entities(profile,conference).now();

         return conference;
         }
    @ApiMethod(name="queryConferences",
            path="queryConferences",
            httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
    public List<Conference> queryConferences(ConferenceQueryForm cqf){

        return cqf.getQuery().list();
    }

    @ApiMethod(name="getConferencesCreated",
            path="getConferencesCreated",
            httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
    public List<Conference> getConferencesCreated(User user) throws UnauthorizedException{
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }
        Query<Conference> query= ofy().load().type(Conference.class).ancestor(Key.create(Profile.class,user.getUserId())).order("name");
        return query.list();
    }

//    @ApiMethod(name="filterPlayground",
//          path="filterPlayground",
//          httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
    public List<Conference> filterPlayground(){
        Query<Conference> query= ofy().load().type(Conference.class);
//      query=query.filter("topics=", "Movie Making");
//      query=query.filter("month=",6);
        query=query.filter("city","London");
        query=query.filter("maxAttendees >",10).order("maxAttendees").order("name");
        return query.list();
    }



}
```

Please tell me if there is something wrong with pom.xml or there are some other issues that are making EspAuthenticator.class not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Endpoints Framework Auth dependency needs to be included. Check out this doc:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management

Comment: It worked for me. I just added those two dependency and it worked for me. Thanks mann.